# How can I grant individual permissions in Google Cloud Platform for BigQuery users using python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I need to set up very fine-grained access control for user accounts in GCP using a python script

I know that via UI/gcloud util I can give it role roles/big query. user, but it has a lot of other permissions I don't want this service account to have.

How can I grant individual permissions via python scripts?

Comment: have you tried this using this JSON  API https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/datasets/update

Comment: Can you be a little more specific to what you're trying to do?

Comment: @GrahamPolley I have created datasets like test1,test2,test3. I have many users like user1, user2,user3.  I want to give access like user1 should access only test1 datasets and perform operations on  test1 datasets and like this using python scripts.

Comment: I'm sorry. I still don't follow you.

Comment: @GrahamPolley datasets name : test1,test2     username : user1,user2   user 1 should access test1 datasets only.  user1 should not able to do any operations on test2 datasets. He should be able to access only test1 datasets using python

Answer (score 1):

Go to your [BigQuery console](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com), click into the arrow at the right of one dataset and then click into `Share dataset`

[image: Share dataset]

And then add the e-mail of the user here:

[image: Add user]

You can choose one of 3 roles available: Viewer/Owner/Editor.

Do this in every dataset to every user.

**Update to do it via Python script**

You can do it with a Python script following [this small tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-datasets#updating_dataset_access_controls).

The code will be something like:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
dataset = client.get_dataset(client.dataset('dataset1'))

entry = bigquery.AccessEntry(
    role='READER',
    entity_type='userByEmail',
    entity_id='user1@example.com')
assert entry not in dataset.access_entries
entries = list(dataset.access_entries)
entries.append(entry)
dataset.access_entries = entries

dataset = client.update_dataset(dataset, ['access_entries'])  # API request

#assert entry in dataset.access_entries
```

Comment: Good one but I want to do this process using a python script

Comment: @Pradeep I updated my answer to add the Python script.